# How does STL work to hash the key of unordered_map<>?

Tags: c++, hash, stl, unordered-map

I am trying to implement a hash map myself, and i want to use an array to do that. But the problem i am currently dealing with is how to hash the key to an hash value. Do i need to used different methods to do the hashing given different types like 'int', 'char', 'string', '*pointer', or is there a way that i can do that all together? I was trying to use **reinterpret_cast(expression)**, but it doesn't work for 'char'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The general approach is to take the raw byte representation of the object and hash it as if it was an array of `unsigned char`s. The standard library (and ***NOT*** "STL", that's an ancient lib!) actually uses specializations of the `std::hash<>` function object template. It is specialized for primitive types as well as often-used-as-a-key types (e. g. `std::string`).

Comment: You can implement a hashing function that takes a `void const*` and a `size_t`. That will work for all POD types that have no padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STL uses a template class which is already defined for most of the basic types. Indeed, in real time scenarios, you must implement it for your own data type if you fall out of these bounds.

The template class is `hash<T>`, take a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).

Mind that templates doesn't work as Java generics, you "fill the hole" with a template specialization for your specific type, you don't have an implementation which works for all of them in this case (unless you define a common base class for the objects you are going to store inside the map, or, as suggested in the comment, you go lower level, and take the raw bytes of the class variables).